# Flutter build fails due to Amplify_core

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-amplify, flutteramplify

I recently upgraded my flutter application to Android V2, and also made my code null safe.

Now when I try to run my code I get the below build error:

```
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core- 
0.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (26, 1): 
Class 'AtomicResult' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract 
fun error(p0: String, p1: String?, p2: Any?): Unit defined in 
io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core- 
0.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (54, 5): 
'error' overrides nothing
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core- 
0.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (66, 26): 
Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':amplify_core:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Things I tried that did not work:

- Clearing build and cache and restarting
- Deleted the amplify_core-0.4.0 from the pub.dartlang.org folder and tried again
- Initialized Amplify again and pulled the environment from the Launch Studio again

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by changing my channel from Master to Stable.

In the next release of Amplify staying on the Master channel won't present this issue.

Comment: could you please provide details on how you solved this issue.